# Deploy Android app to Google Play that contains only service

Tags: android, google-play

I'm working on SDK for Android app developers.

My idea is to provide interface to app developers and have implementation on Service side.

I want to deploy the service as standalone through Google Play.

Is it possible to deploy app to Google Play that contains only service (no activity)?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is perfectly fine, an app doesn't need to have a main intent action, such as live wallpapers etc.

I remember reading about the Account Sync system in android and that actually encourage you to create a separate APK for your service if it's going to be used by multiple apps rather than deploying the same service into multiple APKs

Comment: Maybe you can point me to specific app that did it on the Google Play? I'm mean if there is over 1 million apps, there is a good chance to have one that is service only...

Comment: Wasn't an app, it was actually from the developer site on using the Account Sync system. You can read about it on the bottom of the page here, last paragraph http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html#DistributeService Although I assume the sample app on that page might be what you're looking for.